# What is the correct way to pass a COM Interface back to a library?

Tags: c#, delphi, com, delphi-10.1-berlin

I get an `System.InvalidCastException` runtime error when trying to pass an interface as a parameter from .NET to a DLL. The code fails on the .NET side and never makes it over to Delphi side.

Construct a simple ActiveX library dll in Delphi. Two Automation Objects: `MyContent` and `MyContainer`. `MyContainer` has single method `Add` that takes an `IBase` interface that is inherited by `IMyContent`. `IBase` is an `IDispatch`

```
[
  uuid(E29018FF-F142-4BAE-B7A4-AE0A8847E930),
  version(1.0)

]
library DelphiComLib
{

  importlib("stdole2.tlb");

  interface IMyBase;
  interface IMyContainer;
  coclass MyContainer;
  interface IMyContent;
  coclass MyContent;


  [
    uuid(07D17021-9E7F-4D7A-B861-59A35EC686A0),
    dual,
    oleautomation
  ]
  interface IMyBase: IDispatch
  {
  };

  [
    uuid(A6AB6F7D-8BEB-459F-A2F8-BC06FF81A45D),
    helpstring("Dispatch interface for MyContainer Object"),
    dual,
    oleautomation
  ]
  interface IMyContainer: IDispatch
  {
    [id(0x000000C9)]
    HRESULT _stdcall Add([in] IMyBase* AMyBase);
  };

  [
    uuid(AB82964C-13D7-423B-9B16-A789D5D30421),
    helpstring("Dispatch interface for MyContent Object"),
    dual,
    oleautomation
  ]
  interface IMyContent: IMyBase
  {
  };

  [
    uuid(DDDF77E5-E6A6-4429-BD4A-D9695E9E6CED),
    helpstring("MyContainer Object")
  ]
  coclass MyContainer
  {
    [default] interface IMyContainer;
  };

  [
    uuid(134BF8B2-30C3-4C37-8F74-3F677808300A),
    helpstring("MyContent Object")
  ]
  coclass MyContent
  {
    [default] interface IMyContent;
  };

};
```

The implementation of the classes does not matter. To keep the sample minimal the implementation of `Add` can be left blank. Here is the Container

```
unit Unit1;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  ComObj, ActiveX, DelphiComLib_TLB, StdVcl;

type
  TMyContainer = class(TAutoObject, IMyContainer)
  protected
    procedure Add(const AMyBase: IMyBase); safecall;

  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

procedure TMyContainer.Add(const AMyBase: IMyBase);
begin

end;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyContainer, Class_MyContainer,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

... and the Content

```
unit Unit2;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  ComObj, ActiveX, DelphiComLib_TLB, StdVcl;

type
  TMyContent = class(TAutoObject, IMyContent)
  protected

  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyContent, Class_MyContent,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

Register the library and add a reference to a console application. The following code will produce the runtime error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DelphiComLib;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IMyContainer container = new MyContainer();
            IMyContent content = new MyContent();
            container.Add(content);


        }
    }
}
```

If I create a class in .NET that implements `IBase` I can pass interface back successfully.

Here is the StackTrace from .NET

```
   at System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Object objSrc, IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)
   at DelphiComLib.IMyContainer.Add(IMyBase AMyBase)
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\jaspers\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 15
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with how the interface is passed to your COM DLL.

The error `System.InvalidCastException` is raised simply because casting from `IMyContent` to `IMyBase` fails on the Delphi implementation side. The reason is that strictly speaking your implementation does not directly implement `IMyBase` interface (even though it implements the derived `IMyContent` interface). You can try it:

```
var
  MyContent: IMyContent;
  MyBase: IMyBase;
begin
  MyContent := CoMyContent.Create;
  MyBase := MyContent as IMyBase; // EIntfCastError is raised
end;
```

Your implementing class must implement `IMyBase` **explicitly** for the casting to work:

[image: Implement all interfaces explicitly]

which will change the declaration of your implementing class:

```
type
  TMyContent = class(TAutoObject, IMyContent, IMyBase)
  ...
  end;
```

which in turn will make the casting work for any COM client code (Delphi, C++, .NET, etc.)